# Pyspark filtering items in column of lists

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pyspark

I'm trying to filter data in dataframe. Dataframe `df` has 2 columns - `query` + `href`. In one row: `query` is random string and `href` is a list of strings. I have another list called `urls` with strings.

Looking for finding an URL from list `urls` inside the `href` column lists + position of the url in `href` list. I was trying `df.filter(col("href")).isin(urls)` but pyspark complains about the list. + I'm not able to do .collect() bcs of the amount of the data.

Thanks in advance!

Basically it should look like this but I'm not really sure how to do it in pyspark:

```
for url in urls:
    if url in "href item list":
        print(query + url + "href item list".index(url)) # doesn't matter if index or position
    else:
        pass
```

Example:

```
urls = [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6, url7, url8]

query | href
------------
q1    | [url7, url11, url12, url13, url14]
q2    | [url1, url3, url5, url6]
q3    | [url1, url2, url8]

Output should look like 

q2 - url1 - 0
q3 - url1 - 0
q3 - url2 - 1
q2 - url3 - 1
q2 - url5 - 2
q2 - url6 - 3
q1 - url7 - 0
q3 - url8 - 2
```

Comment: I dont think you need collect here. are u using spark2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest 1) making a single column DataFrame of your `urls` using `explode` and 2) use `posexplode` to make 3-column DataFrame of your query, href, and index-position of href, then 3) inner join the two

1. Create DataFrame of `urls`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, posexplode

urls = [
    (['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6', 'url7', 'url8'],),
]
refs = (
    spark.createDataFrame(urls, ['ref']).
        select(
            explode('ref')
        )
)
refs.show(truncate=False)
# +----+
# |col |
# +----+
# |url1|
# |url2|
# |url3|
# |url4|
# |url5|
# |url6|
# |url7|
# |url8|
# +----+
```

2. Create Example Data you provided

```
data = [
    ("q1", ["url7", "url11", "url12", "url13", "url14"]),
    ("q2", ["url1", "url3", "url5", "url6"]),
    ("q3", ["url1", "url2", "url8"]),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["query", "href"])
df.show(truncate=False)
# +-----+----------------------------------+
# |query|href                              |
# +-----+----------------------------------+
# |q1   |[url7, url11, url12, url13, url14]|
# |q2   |[url1, url3, url5, url6]          |
# |q3   |[url1, url2, url8]                |
# +-----+----------------------------------+
```

3. Solution

```
(
    df.
        select(
            'query',
            posexplode('href')
        ).
        join(
            refs,
            'col',
            'inner'
        ).
        orderBy('col', 'query').
        show(truncate=False)
)
# +----+-----+---+                                                                
# |col |query|pos|
# +----+-----+---+
# |url1|q2   |0  |
# |url1|q3   |0  |
# |url2|q3   |1  |
# |url3|q2   |1  |
# |url5|q2   |2  |
# |url6|q2   |3  |
# |url7|q1   |0  |
# |url8|q3   |2  |
# +----+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps in words:

1. `explode` the column `href`
2. `filter` those rows with a known URL
3. `collect` the results and look up each URL in `urls`

The code below is broken into small steps to make it easier to inspect the intermediate DataFrames.

Assuming you already have a `SparkSession` object called `ss`, we can recreate your original DataFrame like this:

```
df = ss.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("q1", ["url7", "url11", "url12", "url13", "url14"]),
        ("q2", ["url1", "url3", "url5", "url6"]),
        ("q3", ["url1", "url2", "url8"]),
    ],
    ["query", "href"],
)
urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", "url5", "url6", "url7", "url8"]
```

Now we apply the steps described before:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

# Exploding the column "href".
exp_df = df.select("query", sf.explode(sf.col("href")).alias("href_sing"))
# Checking if the URL in the DataFrame exists in "urls".
# I suggest to convert "urls" into a "set" before this step: "set(urls)". It might 
# improve the performance of "isin", but this is just an optional optimization.
known_df = exp_df.select("*", sf.col("href_sing").isin(urls).alias("is_known"))
# Discard unknown URLs.
true_df = true_df = known_df.filter("is_known = True")
# The final results.
res = [
    (r["query"], r["href_sing"], urls.index(r["href_sing"]))
    for r in true_df.collect()
]
```

Inspecting some values:

```
In [18]: df.show()      
+-----+--------------------+
|query|                href|
+-----+--------------------+
|   q1|[url7, url11, url...|
|   q2|[url1, url3, url5...|
|   q3|  [url1, url2, url8]|
+-----+--------------------+

In [19]: exp_df.show()                                                                    
+-----+---------+
|query|href_sing|
+-----+---------+
|   q1|     url7|
|   q1|    url11|
|   q1|    url12|
|   q1|    url13|
|   q1|    url14|
|   q2|     url1|
|   q2|     url3|
|   q2|     url5|
|   q2|     url6|
|   q3|     url1|
|   q3|     url2|
|   q3|     url8|
+-----+---------+

In [20]: true_df.show()                                                                   
+-----+---------+--------+
|query|href_sing|is_known|
+-----+---------+--------+
|   q1|     url7|    true|
|   q2|     url1|    true|
|   q2|     url3|    true|
|   q2|     url5|    true|
|   q2|     url6|    true|
|   q3|     url1|    true|
|   q3|     url2|    true|
|   q3|     url8|    true|
+-----+---------+--------+

In [23]: res                                                                              
Out[23]: 
[('q1', 'url7', 6),
 ('q2', 'url1', 0),
 ('q2', 'url3', 2),
 ('q2', 'url5', 4),
 ('q2', 'url6', 5),
 ('q3', 'url1', 0),
 ('q3', 'url2', 1),
 ('q3', 'url8', 7)]
```